# Dropdown menu border

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to get bottom rounded corner for the dropdown menu or the child items of the parent navigation bar in twenty eleven theme wordpress

```
#access ul ul a {
background: #F9F9F9;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD;
 color: #444;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
height: auto;
line-height: 1.4em;
padding: 10px 10px;
width: 168px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;`
```

If i keep it like this then all the dropdown menu items are getting the border i only regired border for the last item

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:last-child` selector. Here's how your CSS would look like:

```
.menu-item:last-child a {
     border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: No this is not working for my case please check this link http://trichometechnology.com/  about tab

Comment: trichometechnology.com check this like and in the about tab

Comment: i dont know how to use jdfiddle

Comment: @karu Umm, [your CSS file](http://trichometechnology.com/wp-content/themes/constellation/style.css) is still unchanged. You should replace lines 87-89 with what I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: actually changed the removed access ul ul a and added background and bottom border radius to  access ul ul